# Large viewstate in HTML source

Tags: asp.net, html, viewstate, hidden-field

This is 10KB in my HTML source:

```
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="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" />
```

This represents ~50% of the entire size of the page.

Why does it do this, why so long?  Can I do anything about it?  It's bad for mobile users.

Comment: What type of controls are you using on the page? Does the page postback at all?

Comment: Just an idea: As it seems these are mostly comments that are stored in the view state, you could page them or not save them to be in view state.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### What is this view state anyway and how to mitigate its size

In Asp.net WebForms every control saves its state because HTTP protocol is stateless and Asp.net WebForms pages bypass that by saving every control's state in this Base 64 encoded string. This is the only way for Asp.net framework to know whether some control's value has changed or not. But... This automatically means that static controls that don't get POSTed back to server (like label for instance) don't need to save their state. You can always set their `EnableViewState="false"`.

Unfortunately this can't be set without any other code changes on other controls, that do get POSTed back (every server-side control that renders some sort of an input in HTML). This basically means that setting `EnableViewState="false"` on page level (within `@Page` directive) will have consequences that are seen as controls loosing their values, controls not firing certain events etc.

So, the more server-side controls you have the larger it will get (without turning it off on certain controls).

But I wouldn't worry if its size is 10k. That will go back and forth rather fast and painless. You will have problems when it gets much larger. I once worked on a project and we had an issue with a certain page (done by less experienced developer) where view state grew over 1MB. Imagine that. What a slowdown!

### How to turn it off completely on page level

When you turn view state off on page level you have to be aware that certain controls that were loaded (or better said data bound) in on of your page's events, will have to be reloaded each time your page gets POSTed back at server. Otherwise they will show up as empty when your page gets back to the client.

Answer (score 3):

Your server controls are filling the ViewState with data they will need on postback. If your page does not postback you can just disable the ViewState for the page.

To disable ViewState for the page you can just add `EnableViewState="false"` to the `@Page` directive. Please be aware you should only use this as a solution if you are 100% sure the page does not postback.

You also might want to check this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx#viewstate_topic3) to get a better idea of what the ViewState does.

Answer (score 2):

Disable viewstate for static controls, like a gridview.
Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547532/how-to-minimize-viewstate-size-of-a-page-in-asp-net) for more info:

Comment: +1 View state size growth mitigation is probably the best solution to this problem. Turning it off completely requires more processing (usually related to more DB requests).

Comment: @Robert Just wondering, if the page is never posted back and you disable viewstate for the page why would it require more processing?

Answer (score 2):

If you are concerned about the viewstate on the client side, then think about storing it on the server side. Perhaps in a session variable. Take a look at this article as there is statistical comparison given. Download the solution and check out how to store it on the server side.
[An Analysis of Keeping ViewState out of the Page](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20040613.asp)

Comment: Although true this shouldn't be taken so lightly, because sooner or later this become a bottleneck on the server.

Comment: well you are right and thanks for your point., but Its total how much is the traffic to that site.

Comment: Recently we have shifted viewstate from client to server in our application and performance improve much. We used the technique in the provided solution.

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar: I can imagine yes. But scaling your application may become a problem. That's all I wanted to point out. You can easily switch view state store but have to be aware of implications.

Comment: yes, Again you have very good point. But its all about how carefully you handle these things. We have tested after implementation that solution, we fix some code issues but we don't get any scalability issue yet. Lets see in what happen in coming few days, because that product will go live and user will use.

Comment: @Muhammad: I hope you've done some load testing otherwise I'd tick the **brave** box beside your development team. :)

Comment: Smoke testing is done right now, but our QA is writing script for that.

Answer (score 1):

This article explained it neatly to me in the past: [**Taking a Bite Out of ASP.NET ViewState**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972427.aspx).

Basically viewstate's on by default and, depending on which controls you use, it can get out of hand pretty fast. Especially data controls like the gridview are responsible for massive injection of viewstate. You can disable that on a per control basis by setting the EnableViewState property to false. Be careful however as taking out viewstate might also take out functionality of the controls. So do it one by one and test test test.

Another way, and likely better for mobile, is to make use of ASP.NET MVC instead which doesn't have to deal with automatic viewstate injection.